# How to find middle of a curve drawn by p5.js?

Tags: canvas, p5.js

We have:

`p1`: beginning control point

`p2`: first point

`p3`: second point

`p4`: ending control point

Is there any formula to find the middle of the curve?

Here is the reference for the `curve()` function: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/curve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the `curvePoint()` function. You can find more info in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/curvePoint).